# How can I embed a list inside a blockquote

Tags: support, markdown, list, blockquote

I have an answer that I want to use a block quote to cite and outside reference. That reference is a bulleted list.

Pretty sure I have seen this before but I cannot find anyone using it.

How can I use a numbered or bulleted list inside block quotes?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> You don't need HTML:
>
> - a markdown
> - list in quotes
>
> Even with numbers:
>
> 1. more
> 2. less

```
> You don't need HTML:
> 
> * a markdown
> * list in quotes
>
> Even with numbers:
>
> 1. more
> 2. less
```

Comment: I was using `-` for the list when I was testing..... Good to know I can use `*` Thanks.... Crap even `-` is working now... wonder if I have my spacing wrong. Thanks again

Comment: The blank line before the beginning of the list is critical.

Comment: FYI, on Reddit, the comment preview won't allow this (it appears to not work), but when you actually submit the comment, it does (it works as in the above answer).